# Casting linq query result to enum

Tags: c#, linq, enums, linq-to-objects

I have a list of similar object. The objects in this list all have a property named `Name` and an enum type which is named `Mk2Result` but are of enum type `Mk2TestResult`.

Now inside a for loop I wind to see if the current itterator integer is exist in the list as a name of an object:

```
for(......
{
//    
    var query = 
        from pin in _pins 
        where pin.Name == i.ToString() 
        select pin.Mk2Result;

    Mk2TestResult result = (Mk2TestResult)query;

    //Do some more stuff
}
```

But the compiler complains with the following message:

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DataModels.Mk2TestResult>' to 'DataModels.Mk2TestResult'
```

How to correctly return the query result as the enum type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query actually returns a collection of your `Enum` type. If you just want one result, you will have to use the `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, or `FirstOrDefault` extension methods.

**Note:** Use the methods that are named **OrDefault** when you think its possible for the query to return no results.  Empty result sets would cause an exception when calling `Single` or `First`.

```
var query = 
    from pin in _pins 
    where pin.Name == i.ToString() 
    select pin.Mk2Result;

// If pin.Mk2Result is strongly typed, the cast is not necessary
Mk2TestResult result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
Mk2TestResult result = (Mk2TestResult)query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Because you are trying to cast list to one object.
But you will get only the first object. You can use a funcion inside FirstOrDefault function parameters to get the object you need.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the query is a collection of elements, not the single one. That is what compiler is trying to say you. If you want to get the first value from this collection you should use [Enumerable.First Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx). If you want to have superposition of the `Mk2TestResult` you can use the [Enumerable.Aggregate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx). Or you could simply iterate through the collection and perform some action based on the concrete `Mk2TestResult` value.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to cast a collection of Mk2TestResult objects to just one so either get the FirstOrDefault or cast to an IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

Linq returns IEnumerable, so you have to iterate throught it:

```
var query = 
    (from pin in _pins 
    where pin.Name == i.ToString() 
    select pin.Mk2Result).ToList();

foreach(var result in query)
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Type you are returning is a collection of Mk2TestResul so you need to store it in a List or Array or anything that implements IEnumerable.

Example:

```
List<Mk2TestResult> result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

To add a new Enum type to Dynamic linq, you must add the following code :

```
typeof(Enum),
typeof(T)

T : Enum Type.
```

to the predefinedTypes property of dynamic.

That's work for me